# How to inlcude Mootools script in HTML

Tags: mootools

If I have some Mootools script, do I include the script in HTML like so?

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent("domready", function(){
        $$('div.rj_insertcode a.glossarylink, .no_glossary a.glossarylink').each(function(el) {
                new Element("span", {
                    html: el.get("html")
                }).replaces(el);
    });  
    });   
    </script>
    </head>
```

I am using Joomla with "System - Mootools Upgrade" plugin enabled (so MT 1.2.4 is already included and ready to use).